Apache echarts with Blazor: how to set series disabled by default
I'm using Apache ECharts with Blazor, and I want to set a series disabled by default, so that the user has to clicked on the legend entry to show its data in the chart. I found out how to do that in the original library, but I didn't get it in blazor resp. c#. I don't know how to instantiate a valid select-object:
_echart.Options.Series =
[
        new LineSeries
    {
        Name = "Dauer RA",
        Data = chartValues.Select(v => v.AvgDuration),
        YAxisIndex = 1,
        Select = new Select
        {
            Disabled = true,
            Label = null,
            ItemStyle = null,
            LabelLine = null,
            LineStyle = null,
            AreaStyle = null,
            EndLabel = null,
            UpperLabel = null,
            EdgeLabel = null
        }
    }
];

does not have an (visible) effect. And
_echart.Options.Legend.Selected = new Selected() { "Dauer RA":false };

raises a syntax error.
I don't know how to convert the javascript solution to C#/Blazor :-( .

I dont know any c# but in this example the pie.data property is a list object. So I could imagine that the correct syntax would be something like Legend = new() { Selected = new List<T>() {...} } but I'm not quite sure which type T should be. In typescript it could be Record<string, boolean>

Also the series.select property is not assiciated with the selection in the legend but with selecting datapoints within a series controlled by selecteMode as in this example

Thank you for your input, @matthias, especially for the clarification in your second note.
In C# the class Legend needs an class object Selected at that property, a List or a Dictionary or a KeyValuePair[] does not work. Setting the property with a new Selected object is working, but that class has no parameters, no public properties or methods; I don't know how to use it. Maybe it's a problem of a unsufficient converting to /wrapping for blazor? But the Selected class exists ...

Echarts uses a Dictionary<boolean> in the LegendModel. I have seen several issues about echarts not exporting all neccessary types, might be the issue here. Another option would be to use chart actions and unselect the series immediately after initialization (if this is supported by your framework)

I think disabling a chart by default is not possible yet, but a solution is on its way. I will wait until the next version, determine if it works, and if so, then close this issue here. Thank you very much for your efforts, @matthias-mertens !
